# ViewExpiredException when trying to login after a session time out

Tags: primefaces, spring-security, jsf-2.2, atmosphere, prettyfaces

I am developing a simple JSF application.

The welcome bean is as follows

```
package com.test.testclass;

import java.io.IOException; import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped; import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.push.EventBus; import org.primefaces.push.EventBusFactory; import org.primefaces.push.annotation.OnMessage; import org.primefaces.push.annotation.PushEndpoint; import org.primefaces.push.impl.JSONEncoder;


@ManagedBean @SessionScoped @com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMapping(
                id = "welcomeBean",
                pattern = "/welcome/",
                viewId = "/welcome.xhtml") public class WelcomeBean implements Serializable {
    /**
     * End point for pushing notifications to browser to automatically update
     */
    @PushEndpoint(Channel.NAME)
    public static class Channel {
        public static final String NAME = "/testChannel";


        @OnMessage(encoders = { JSONEncoder.class })
        public String onMessage(String count) {
            return count;
        }
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private volatile int count;


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }


    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }


    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }


    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }


    public void increment() {
        count++;
        EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
        eventBus.publish("/message", String.valueOf(count));
    }


    public void logout() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        try {
            context.getExternalContext().redirect("login.xhtml");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } }
```

The session time out is set by the following class

```
package com.test.testclass;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler;


public class SessionTimeOutSetter
                extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(5);
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

The following xhtml files are used

Welcome.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:prime="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form method="post" id="welcomeForm">
        <prime:socket channel="/testChannel">
            <prime:ajax event="message" update=":welcomeForm" />
        </prime:socket>
        <h2>Welcome #{welcomeBean.username}</h2>
        <h3>The number of clicks are #{welcomeBean.count}</h3>
        <h:commandButton value="Increment count"
            actionListener="#{welcomeBean.increment}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Logout" action="#{welcomeBean.logout}"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Login.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:prime="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <h2>Hello user.</h2>
    <form method="post" action="/testProject/j_spring_security_check">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <prime:outputLabel value="Username:" />
            <prime:inputText type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username" />

            <prime:outputLabel value="Password:" />
            <prime:inputText type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" />

            <button id="Login" type="submit">Login</button>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>Test Project</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <description>
                Set this flag to true, if you want the JavaServer Faces Reference
                Implementation to validate the XML in your faces-config.xml
                resources against the DTD. Default value is false.
        </description>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <description>
                Set this flag to true, if you want the JavaServer Faces Reference
                Implementation to verify that all of the application objects you
                have configured (components, converters, renderers, and
                validators) can be successfully created. Default value is false.
        </description>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
        <!-- Must have <async-supported> set to true cause PrimeFaces Push expects all
        filters in the chain support it or it leads to an IllegalStateException. -->
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>    

    <!-- Faces Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- PrimeFaces push -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Applicationcontext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="admin" password="a" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome/**"
            access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
        <security:session-management
            invalid-session-url="/login.xhtml" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml"
            default-target-url="/welcome/" authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml"
            always-use-default-target="true" authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login.xhtml" />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="authSuccessHandler" class="com.test.testclass.SessionTimeOutSetter" />
</beans>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>welcome</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

The problem is that I get a ViewExpiredException when I try to login after a session time out. I have hard coded the session timeout value to 5 seconds. But the session takes much more than that to time out. Also if I replace h:body tag with body in welcome.xhtml, the application works just fine. But I need h:body in my application. Is there any way in which I can keep the h:body tag and not run into such an exception.

The exception is as follows

```
[2018-01-22T19:20:56.396-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [FATAL] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1516666856396] [levelValue: 1100] [[
  viewId:/welcome.xhtml - View /welcome.xhtml could not be restored.
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/welcome.xhtml - View /welcome.xhtml could not be restored.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:210)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

I am using JSF 2.2, Spring security 3.2.5, atmosphere 2.4.9, Spring 4.1.4, primefaces 6.1 and pretty faces 3.3.3.

Comment: Deja-vu and I was right ;-)... Why did you not continue on your other **identical** question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157607/viewexpiredexception-when-using-primefaces-socket

Comment: I just thought of writing another one with a complete working example. to make things clearer. :-)

Comment: So if you don't use pretttyfaces it works? Or if you don't use spring-security but plain/simple username password check? Of if you don't use a navigation rule? Please try to make your example minimal as well. See [mcve]... And please remove the other question then.

Comment: It works with everything, except the h:body tag in welcome.xhtml. If I replace it with body, then it works.